# Calculating catalan numbers with memoization

Tags: python, python-2.7, recursion, memoization, catalan

I am trying to use memoization in order to calculate catalan numbers, but it just does not seem to work, what do I need to change?

```
def catalan_mem(n, mem = None):
    if n==0:
        return 1
    if mem==None:
        mem={}
    sum=0
    if n not in mem:
        for i in range(0, n):
            sum = sum + catalan_mem(i) * catalan_mem(n-i-1)
        mem[n]=sum
    return mem[n]
```

Comment: pass `mem` as parameter to the recursive calls

Comment: Or define `mem` as global

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the cache to your recursive calls:

```
sum = sum + catalan_mem(i, mem) * catalan_mem(n-i-1, mem)
```

Otherwise, every method call creates a new empty cache.